# How to process pdf files with the help a mapreduce?

Tags: pdf, mapreduce

The task parse many pdf using hadoop mapreduce. I think that the whole process should only be in the mapper. Where to start? How the mapper has to look?

Comment: Each `Mapper` processes part of the whole data set. If the result requires the whole data set involved computing/processing, `Reducer` is needed. Otherwise MapReduce framework is not necessary. So what's your question?

Comment: Need to convert text from pdf to txt. Since pdf files are so many I think the handle on Amazon. I'm interested in how to properly write the most mapreduce.What do you advise?

Comment: Do you mean you have many PDF files, and want to convert each PDF file to a txt file? If so, `MapReduce` framework is not very necessary, but certainly it can achieve. While if you want to convert all PDF files to a single txt file, then `MapReduce` is a pretty good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with you that the parsing process can be done in **Mapper** part, and the **Reducer** part simply output the result without any aggregation computing.

Use the widely used MapReduce framework **Hadoop** as example, you need to define your own data type using [Writable](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Writable.html), suppose name it as `MyPdfFile`, each `MyPdfFile` instance represents a PDF file, it contains the input PDF file content and maybe other info. `MyPdfFile` should include a method `getConvertedText` which convert PDF file content to text, about how to process PDF files via Java, try [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/).

Then the `Mapper` maybe looks like:

```
class PdfToTxtMapper extends Mapper<Text, MyPdfFile, Text, Text> {
  @Override
  public void map(Text inputKey, PdfFile inputValue, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Text outputKey = new Text(inputKey);
    Text outputVal = inputValue.getConvertedText(inputValue);
    context.write(outputKey, outputVal);
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.